# How to create p element function once and use it in each function to print on the screen

Tags: javascript, function

Below is my code of longer version and i need a shorter way. I wanted to make a function to create a p element and append it, but the problem i faced was the variable scope.
Please help!!! The code below is working perfectly but is a longer version.

```
    const input = document.querySelector('.input-num');

    function squared(num){
        
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        para.textContent = "square of " + num + " is " + num * num;
    }

    function cubed(num){
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        para.textContent = "cube of " + num + " is " + num * num * num;
    }

    function areaOfCircle(num){
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        para.textContent = "Area of circle with radius as " + num + " is " + Math.PI * num * num;
    }

    function circumferenceOfCircle(num){
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        para.textContent = "Circumference of circle with radius as " + num + " is " + 2 * Math.PI * num;
    }

    function factorial(num){
        if(num < 0) return undefined;
        if(num == 0) return 1;
        let initialNum = num;
        let x = num -1;
        while(x > 1){
            num *= x;
            x--;
        }
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        para.textContent = "factorial of " + initialNum + " is " + num;
    }
    

    input.onchange = function(){

        const num = parseFloat(input.value);
        if(isNaN(num)){
            const para = document.createElement('p');
            document.body.appendChild(para);
            para.textContent = 'You need to enter a number';
        } else{
            squared(num);
            cubed(num);
            areaOfCircle(num);
            circumferenceOfCircle(num);
            factorial(num);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function that does the repetitive bits `

```
function dry(text) { 
    const para = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(para);
    para.textContent = text;
}
```

Now you can simply do

```
function squared(num) {
    dry("square of " + num + " is " + num * num);
}
```

p.s. the name of function `dry` doesn't matter, I used dry, as it stand for don't repeat yourself

Also: This is "shorter" but less readable

```
function dry(text) { 
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).textContent = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a input element on your page.
Take a look.
explaination is in the code.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input-num');

// we are going to make a function for creating a paragraph, appending to body and displaying text.

function createPara(mymsg, mynum, myformula) {
    const para = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(para);

    // using string interpolation is exellent way to format messages.
    // first argument 'mymsg' is your msg you want to display
    // second argument is 'mynum' that your input number
    // third argument is 'myformula' because your every function in your code has different formula.

    para.textContent = `${mymsg} ${mynum} is ${myformula}`;
}

function squared(num) {

    // we define formula to a variable, just so that it's easy to read.

    let formula = num * num;
    createPara('square of ', num, formula);
}

function cubed(num) {
    let formula = num * num * num;
    createPara('cube of ', num, formula);
}

function areaOfCircle(num) {

    let formula = (Math.PI * num * num);
    createPara('Area of circle with radius as ', num, formula);
}

function circumferenceOfCircle(num) {

    let formula = (2 * Math.PI * num);
    createPara('Circumference of circle with radius as ', num, formula);
}

function factorial(num) {
    if (num < 0) return undefined;
    if (num == 0) return 1;
    let initialNum = num;
    let x = num - 1;
    while (x > 1) {
        num *= x;
        x--;
    }

    createPara('factorial of ', initialNum, num);
}


// this is function for removing the old paragraphs created on first input.
// try commenting this out and see the effect. you will understand.
function removePara() {
    const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
    console.log(paragraphs.length);
    if (paragraphs.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            document.body.removeChild(paragraphs[i]);
        }
    }
}

input.onchange = function () {

    removePara();

    const num = parseFloat(input.value);
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        createPara('You need to enter a number', null, null);
    } else {
        squared(num);
        cubed(num);
        areaOfCircle(num);
        circumferenceOfCircle(num);
        factorial(num);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="input-num" />
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```